# Presentation with latex, changing the width in each frame

Tags: latex, presentation, beamer

In my presentation, I use `\usetheme{Warsaw}` and in order to increase the usable space in each frame, I use `\useoutertheme{infolines}`. In this way, the bar at the bottom of each page is equally divided between author's name, title, and date and slide number. Is there anyway to change the width of each section? For example, I need more space for the title compared to author's name or date. Any comment is highly appreciated. Also, the code I am using is the following:

```
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\title[...]{...}
\author[...]{...}
\institute{...}
\date{...}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Find the `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty` file (in the `...\latex\beamer\themes\outer` folder). You will see that the 1:1:1 width is hard-coded using `wd=.333333\paperwidth` for each box, so you will have to edit the style file.

The following is not tested, but should set you on the right path.
Change those values as you want, then save the file under a different name, say `beamerouterthemeunevenlines.sty`. Now use `unevenlines` as your outer theme.